# Make a UISwitch hide/unhide a label when it toggles on/off

Tags: ios, swift3, segue, viewcontroller, uiswitch

`MeditationSettingsViewController` has a `UISwitch` which is linked to `MeditationScreenViewController` though a Segue. The `UISwitch` doesn't hide the text in the label called `phaselabel` from `MeditationScreenViewController` but instead displays the `MeditationSettingsViewController` screen. How do I get it so that the switch doesn't do this but hides and unhides `phaselabel` when the switch is turned on/off?

```
class MeditationSettingsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func showCycleTitleChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if (sender.isOn == true)
    {
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "segue" {
                if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MeditationScreenViewController {
                    sendToDetailViewController.isSwitchOn = sender!.isOn
                }

            }

class MeditationScreenViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if isSwitchOn == true {
      //unhide the label
      self.phaseLabel.isHidden = true
        //set your label value here
    }
    else {
        self.phaseLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the switch toggling on/off to hide/unhide the phaselabel in another view controller, right? How does the MeditationScreenViewController get shown on screen?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It gets shown by clicking cancel on a popup window. The popup window is connected to the MeditationSettingsViewController.

Comment: You somehow need to get a (weak) reference to the `phaselabel` in `MeditationSettingsViewController` so that you can hide/unhide it. Another way to do this would be to let the `MeditationScreenViewController` somehow listen (by using NSNotificationCenter or delegation) to the switch toggles and then hide/unhide the label there. It is difficult for me to give code for this without knowing the structure of your project.

Comment: Ok, apple do it on there interface, togging on/off button to activate things in different view controllers. Please let me know what extra code you need from the project?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use NSNotificationCenter. Hopefully that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the code but an error came up and it says 'cannot convert value of type'Bool' to expected argument type [AnyHasable: Any]' This is in the MeditationSettingsViewController in the showCycleTitleChanged function. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I can use a Bool as it's a Label I'm hiding and unhiding.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I had not tested the nsnotification code before writing it here (I'm not too familiar with the Swift 3 syntax). I have edited it so that it should work now.

Comment: Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NSNotificationCenter` to let the two view controllers be aware of the switch state change.

In `MeditationSettingsViewController` in the `showCycleTitleChanged` function, do this:

```
@IBAction func showCycleTitleChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    let data:[String: Bool] = ["state": sender!.isOn]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "switchChanged"), object: nil, userInfo: data)
}
```

In `MeditationScreenViewController`, listen to the notification like so:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showHideLabel(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "switchChanged"), object: nil)
```

Also add this function to handle the notification:

```
func showHideLabel(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    self.phaselabel.isHidden = notification.userInfo?["state"] as? Bool
}
```

Comment: It says 'MeditationSettingsViewController' has no member phaselabel so doesn't work.

Comment: Yes showCycleTitleChanged is connected to the valueChanged of the UISwitch.

Comment: Is it normal for calling a function inside ibaction??

Comment: @user8270584 Yes, it is.

Comment: @aksh1t i meant to define a function inside ??

Comment: @user8270584 Oh that; IMO, that is not a common thing. I believe that nested functions are allowed in Swift, but they are not commonly used like that. Unnamed functions (blocks) are much more common.

Comment: @aksh1t so how does it work in this case??
I know that when you call performSegueWithIdentifier method, the control automatically comes to prepareForSegue before excecuting the segue, right?

Comment: The way I've done it in my answer, the switch action sends out a notification called "switchChanged" bundled with the updated value of the switch. Whoever is listening to the "switchChanged" notification (in this case showHideLabel function) gets notified and that code executes. This is a very common pattern for data passing where the objects are weakly related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153995/discussion-between-aksh1t-and-user8270584).